# Java Properties backslash

Tags: java, properties

I am using Java Properties to read a properties file. Everything is working fine, but Properties silently drops the backslashes.

(i.e.)

```
original: c:\sdjf\slkdfj.jpg

after: c:sdjfslkdfj.jpg
```

How do I make Properties not do this?

I am using the code `prop.getProperty(key)`

I am getting the properties from a file, and I want to avoid adding double backslashes

Comment: Syntax of property file described here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)

Comment: Backslashes are for escaped character sequences and split lines. Also note that you can use normal '/' slashes for pathnames in Windows.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It is [Properties.load()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) that's causing the problem that you are seeing as backslash is used for a special purpose.

> The logical line holding all the data
>   for a key-element pair may be spread
>   out across several adjacent natural
>   lines by escaping the line terminator
>   sequence with a backslash character,
>   \.

If you are unable to use CoolBeans's suggestion then what you can do is read the property file beforehand to a string and replace backslash with double-backslash and then feed it to Properties.load()

```
String propertyFileContents = readPropertyFileContents();

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new StringReader(propertyFileContents.replace("\\", "\\\\")));
```

Comment: The multiline property values won't be recognized any more. See my post for a solution.

Answer (score 25):

Use double backslashes `c:\\sdjf\\slkdfj.jpg`

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("test", "C:\\dev\\sdk\\test.dat");
System.out.println(props.getProperty("test"));    // prints C:\dev\sdk\test.dat
```

**UPDATE** CREDIT to **@ewh** below. Apparently, Windows recognises front slashes. So, I guess you can have your users write it with front slashes instead and if you need backslashes afterwards you can do a replace. I tested this snippet below and it works fine.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("test", "C:/dev/sdk/test.dat");
System.out.println(props.getProperty("test"));   // prints C:/dev/sdk/test.dat
```

Comment: I want to avoid using double backslashes, since I am getting the properties from a user-written file.

Comment: Sorry - you didn't have that info in your post initially. If you are on windows/DOS file system then I am afraid you are out of luck.

Comment: You are not out-of-luck on Windows systems.  You can actually use forward slashes in pathnames on windows systems.  I normally do this in java properties files to avoid messing with backslashes.

Answer (score 12):

Use *forward* slashes. There is never a need in Java to use a backslash in a filename.

Answer (score 7):

In case you really need a backslash in a properties file that will be loaded (like for a property that is not a file path) **put `\u005c` for each backslash character**.

The backslash is treated specially in properties files as indicated in the document provided by @unhillbilly.

@EJP: Backslash is definitely needed if, for example, you wanted to store an NTLM login id in a properties file, where the format is  `DOMAIN\USERNAME` with a backslash. This type of property is **not** a filename so forward slashes will not work.

Edit: @Max Nanasy: From the document ([java.util.Properties load javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29)) mentioned above (emphasis mine)

> The method does not treat a backslash character, '\', before a non-valid escape character as an error; **the backslash is silently dropped**. For example, in a Java string the sequence "\z" would cause a compile time error. In contrast, this method silently drops the backslash. Therefore, this method treats the two character sequence "\b" as equivalent to the single character 'b'

For me, I always had trouble with backslashes in the properties file (even with double backslash '\\') unless I specified the unicode.

Comment: Why would you use `\u005c` instead of `\\\`?  It's less readable and more typing.

Comment: Also, how do I format '\\' like code in a Stack Exchange comment?

Comment: @MaxNanasy use back ticks `//`

Comment: @Alex That works for forward slashes (`//`), but I can't seem to get it to work with backslashes (`\\`).

Comment: @frooble The document you reference is detailing the differences between properties-file escaping and Java String literal escaping.  In Java String literals, two backslashes is a valid escape sequence, and therefore the section you're quoting is irrelevant; even if two backslashes were not a valid escape sequence, the section you quote implies that it would represent a single backslash, since it would silently drop the first backslash.  I don't know why you have trouble with double backslashes, but it seems to be the proper way to escape a single backslash according to the documentation.

Comment: @Max Nanasy: the OP was asking about loading properties from **files**, not setting properties via Java String literals.  The [load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) document referenced is for property files loading.

Comment: @frooble I agree with both of those sentences.  However, the load JavaDoc says: "Characters in keys and elements can be represented in **escape sequences similar to those used for character and string literals** (see sections 3.3 and 3.10.6 of The Java™ Language Specification). The differences from the character escape sequences and Unicode escapes used for characters and strings are: ... The method does not treat a backslash character, \, before a **non-valid** escape character as an error; the backslash is silently dropped ..." (emphasis mine).

Comment: @frooble Since two backslashes in Java String literals is a valid escape sequence, and there's no other rule in the JavaDoc that differentiates double-backslash handling between String literals and properties files, a double backslash in properties files must represent the same thing as in Java String literals, i.e. a single backslash.

Comment: @frooble However, this is all academic reasoning; I've created a simple [proof-of-concept](https://ideone.com/mB9eYD) that shows that two backslashes in a properties file is parsed as a single backslash (note that it's four backslashes in the source code to compensate for being in a string literal).  Can you create a similar proof-of-concept that shows that this is not the case?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `\` with `\\` as below:

```
c:\sdjf\slkdfj.jpg
```

to

```
c:\\sdjf\\slkdfj.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Bala R's answer I have the following solution to even keep the newline-semantic of backslashes at the end of a line.

Here is my code:

```
private static Reader preparePropertyFile(File file) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    boolean endingBackslash = false;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        if (endingBackslash) {

            // if the line is empty, is a comment or holds a new property
            // definition the backslash found at the end of the previous
            // line is not for a multiline property value.
            if (line.isEmpty()
                    || line.startsWith("#")
                    || line.matches("^\\w+(\\.\\w+)*=")) {

                result.append("\\\\");
            }
        }

        // if a backslash is found at the end of the line remove it
        // and decide what to do depending on the next line.
        if (line.endsWith("\\")) {
            endingBackslash = true;
            line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
        } else {
            endingBackslash = false;
        }
        result.append(line.replace("\\", "\\\\"));
    }
    if (endingBackslash) {
        result.append("\\\\");
    }
    return new StringReader(result.toString());
}

private static Properties getProperties(File file) throws IOException {
    Properties result = new Properties();
    result.load(preparePropertyFile(file));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help :

```
BufferedReader metadataReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("migrateSchemaGenProps.properties")));
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new StringReader(IOUtils.getStringFromReader(metadataReader).replace("\\", "/")));
```

Comment: You need a replaceAll, as there can be several backslashes in the properties-file

Comment: @OlivierFaucheux That's wrong. [See the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: @OlivierFaucheux That's wrong. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)): `replace` replaces all occurrences. `replaceAll` won't work since '\\' is no valid regex.

Answer (score 0):

It is not realy a good thing to use backslashes in a property-file, as they are the escape character.

Nevertheless: a Windows user will trend to use them in any path... Therefore, in a single line thanks apache common IO:

```
params.load(new StringReader(IOUtils.toString(paramFile.toURI(), null).replaceAll("\\\\", "/")));
```

Answer (score 0):

you triple use the backslash to get one:
for example:
key=value1\\value2
in the properties file will turn to
key=value1\value2
in the java Properties object