# Java Properties, getting file path

Tags: java, properties, filepath

```
logpath = LoggerUtils.getProperties().getProperty("log.path");
System.out.println("logpath: " + logpath);
```

The above code returns:

```
logpath: C:UsersMauriceDesktopLogs
```

In the properties file is:

```
log.path    C:\Users\Maurice\Desktop\Logs
```

How do I retain the file separators? I want this to work on Linux as well and not just Windows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, you need to put this in the property file:

```
log.path    C:\\Users\\Maurice\\Desktop\\Logs
```

See this:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

more precisely the `load` method:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)

Scroll down a bit and you will see this among other things:

> The method does not treat a backslash character, \, before a non-valid escape character as an error; the backslash is silently dropped. For example, in a Java string the sequence "\z" would cause a compile time error. In contrast, this method silently drops the backslash. Therefore, this method treats the two character sequence "\b" as equivalent to the single character 'b'.

Backslash `\` is an escape character that is silently dropped otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. Does it need to escape as well for Linux?

Comment: Yes, but I'd suggest using regular slashes (`/`) all the time - this will work on Windows, too: `log.path    C:/Users/Maurice/Desktop/Logs`

Comment: Bala R makes a good suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5785128/1551209
To pre-load the contents of the file and replace "\" with "\\" I mention this because I'm working with user-defined JDBC connection URL's and I need these backslashes preserved. This method will work well for anyone else facing the same dilema :)

Answer (score 4):

In a property file, you need to either use forward slashes:

```
C:/Users/Maurice/Desktop/Logs
```

Or, escaped backslashes:

```
C:\\Users\\Maurice\\Desktop\\Logs
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the slashes as they are special characters. See: [Java Properties backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784895/java-properties-backslash)

Answer (score 2):

The Java [properties file format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) dictates that the backslash character ("`\`") escapes the character that follow it, so to get a literal windows path you must have:

```
logpath: C:\\Users\\Maurice\\Desktop\\Logs
```

However, Java will convert path separator characters for you automatically to suit the runtime platform, so you can avoid this nuisance by always using forward slashes:

```
logpath: C:/Users/Maurice/Desktop/Logs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `Properties` to file *first*, then load it again to use. `Properties` will take care of escaping/ unescaping anything.