# How to create a new directory using java?

Tags: java, directory

I am using the following code to create folder but it does not create it (output is failed) and does not throw any exception.

Folder java is already created, I need to pass the folder name and create it in the java folder.

```
private String CreateFolder(String myfolder) {
        try {
            String dir = "../Java/" + myfolder;
            boolean result = false;
            File directory = new File(dir);

            if (!directory.exists()) {
                result = directory.mkdir();

                if (result) {
                    System.out.println("Folder is created");
                    return dir;
                } else {
                    return "failed";
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: What is the result of you method (the returned value)?

Comment: The String dir isn't an absolute path. It should be something like `"C:/Java/" + folder` (Windows) or `/home/whatever/" + folder` (Linux)

Comment: @maqjav I'm pretty sure it won't matter

Comment: @maqjav I am on server

Comment: **..** means one directory up.
(if you have app in `Java/bin/` and want to execute file from `Java/main/` you can use **..** for one directory up)
**.** means same directory.
(if you have app in `Java/bin/` and want to execute file from same directory `Java/bin/` you can use **.** for same directory)

Comment: @MirMoorido Works fine for me. Do you have the correct permissions to create a folder in the specified location

Comment: try changing
`String dir = "../Java/" + myfolder;` to `String dir = "./Java/" + myfolder;` *(or give exact location of folder)*

Comment: if no absolute path is given. The folder might be created in temp directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try giving absolute path to the directory instead of relative path.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this :

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String path = "E:\\test";
    createFolder(path);
}

private static boolean createFolder(String theFilePath)
{
    boolean result = false;

    File directory = new File(theFilePath);

    if (directory.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Folder already exists");
    } else {
        result = directory.mkdirs();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Make sure to use correct root dir path (for example if you want to create folder inside of "../somefolder" it must be created already) if you want to use **mkdir()**.

**Note** you need to set two slashes after Drive name. Like this **"E:\\"**.

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371288/java-properties-getting-file-path).

Answer (score 0):

You can try File.mkdirs() to try make nest directories and print the directory absolute path. I think you use the wrong path of "Java".

```
System.out.println(directory.getAbsolutePath())
```

Comment: as he is on server it shows his server path not the system path

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the folder `../Java/` exits. If there is no folder `Java`. The code won't work. If you really want create folder `Java` automaticlly. Please use `direcotry.mkdirs()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Is this part of a web application? then use context path instead of abs path.
Also use File.separator instead of slashes(/)