# Properties path value

Tags: java, properties, escaping

I want to store the path to an Excelfile in a config.cfg file. This file is then loaded:

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.load(new FileInputStream(path));
```

I can now read in all keys and their corresponding values. `key = value`

In the config file, there is a path. This path points to a server.

Windows shows the paths the following way: `\\192.168.244.5\folder\folder`

The Properties variable can't read in the `\`... only if in the config file the path is like this: `\\\\192.168.244.5\\folder\\folder` But if the user wants to replace the path, he has to add a `\` for every `\`.

Isn't it possible to define that the Properties variable can read in the `\`? Also I can't change all the `\` to / because the server isn't recognized this way.

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.load(new FileInputStream(path));

config.getProperty("excelPath");
```

If the path is stored:

```
excelPath = \\192.168.244.5\folder\folder
```

The output is `\192.168.244.5folderfolder`

But shouldn't this value be a String, so because it's read in by an FileInputStream the \ should be recognized as char, not as escape-character.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784895/java-properties-backslash

Comment: `But shouldn't this value be a String` Run this `System.out.println("\\192.168.244.5\folder\folder");` and you ll know.

Comment: Well... stupid me. Thank you