# reading windows paths in properties file

Tags: java, duplicates

I am reading windows file paths from a properties file in Java. I do really need my program to handle unscaped paths, but so far I cannot see how to do it.

The properties key-value:

> file.path = C:\directory

The code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load("filename.properties");
properties.getProperty("file.path");
```

The undesired result:

```
C:directory
```

---

UPDATE: Duplicate question [stackoverflow.com/questions/5784895/java-properties-backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784895/java-properties-backslash)

Comment: The `:` and "\" characters need to be escaped, something like `C\:\\directory` (in the file)

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784895/java-properties-backslash

Answer (score 22):

You can escape it using `\\`:

```
file.path = C:\\directory
```

Or, you may also use forward slash instead:

```
file.path = C:/directory
```