# How to create two lines in JTable header using LocaleString

Tags: java, swing, jtable, multiline, tableheader

I am trying to create two lines in JTable header using LocaleString like the picture below.

[image]

source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiLineHeaderExample.htm

I've researched many places online and they seem to give solutions for String not LocaleString. (I used a backslash in String and it works (creating two lines in JTable header)).

However, if I use a backslash in LocaleString (value inside property file), it doesn't do anything.

I've also tried,

\r - doesn't show any in GUI

\r\r - doesn't show any in GUI

\r - shows \r

"\r" - shows ""

\"\r\" - shows ""

\ - shows \

I tried with letter n applying the same logic above and it doesn't work.

What would be easiest and the best way to achieve this?

Comment: The Windows newline is `\r\n`, have you tried that?  Sometimes you need to double-up the backslash: `\\r`, `\\n` or `\\r\\n`.

Comment: @rossum I just tried it \r\n doesn't show anything and \\r only shows \r.

Comment: I think I just might have found the solution from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784895/java-properties-backslash
I will try this to see if it works in the JTable header