# Get an error when connecting to Firebird database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

Springboot:
pom.xml 
   org.firebirdsql.jdbc  jaybird  4.0.0.java8

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:firebirdsql://SERVER:3050/D:\company\DbPro\Data\file.fdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
```

I get an error when querying the database:

> Error querying database.  Cause:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
>   obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: I/O
>   error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file
>   "D:companyDbProDatafile.fdb"; Error while trying to open file;
>   [SQLState:08001, ISC error code:335544344]

What's wrong?

Comment: Related, technically duplicate: [Java Properties backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784895/java-properties-backslash) (I decided not to use my gold hammer to close, because I also provide a Firebird-specific alternative in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the error message, Firebird tries to connect to a database `D:companyDbProDatafile.fdb`, which doesn't exist (or is otherwise inaccessible).

The reason your path is incorrect, is that `\` denotes an escape in a properties file. As documented on [`Properties.load`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)):

> - The method does not treat a backslash character, `\`, before a
>   non-valid escape character as an error; the backslash is silently
>   dropped. For example, in a Java string the sequence "`\z`" would cause
>   a compile time error. In contrast, this method silently drops the
>   backslash. Therefore, this method treats the two character sequence
>   "`\b`" as equivalent to the single character '`b`'.

To fix this, make sure to double back-slashes, or use the forward slash instead. So use:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:firebirdsql://SERVER:3050/D:\\company\\DbPro\\Data\\file.fdb
```

or

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:firebirdsql://SERVER:3050/D:/company/DbPro/Data/file.fdb
```

Alternatively, instead of specifying a path to your database, configure an alias in `databases.conf` (Firebird 3 and higher) or `aliases.conf` (Firebird 2.5 and lower) and specify the alias in your connection string instead of the path.

Comment: @AndreyKonus If my answer solved your problem, then please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: `because the path is invalid`, well, *technically* this path is perfectly valid, but in practice it is so random that... run like hell!!! :-D But valid it is.

Comment: @Arioch'The It is questionable if the path `D:companyDbProDatafile.fdb` without a backslash after the driveletter is valid.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel if you do not override OS standards with you own ad hoc definition (and you did not say you do) then is is not questionable, it is valid path.  File or folder "companyDbProDatafile.fdb" placed inside the current folder of drive D:

Comment: @Arioch'The Do you have a citation for that, because as far as I'm aware, that behaviour only exists in the command prompt and only for compatibility with DOS.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it definitely is because of CP/M (not even DOS) legacy, but heritage is not synonimous to invalidity. First link in Microsoft Bing: "If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the current directory on the drive" - just one option listed among many other options of constructing valid filenames at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file